# Does Oracle12c optimizer adaptive features eliminate need for indexes?

Tags: optimization, indexing, oracle12c

My DBA thinks the new Oracle12c optimizer features means he doesn't need to add indexes on important columns anymore. I am having a hard time believing that can possibly be true. It only seems to improve how joins are performed based on historical statistics.

Comment: Your DBA is in serious need of training and understand how Oracle works.

Comment: What time is it?  Time for a new DBA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, he has totally misunderstood.  You can read about Adaptive Query Optimization [in this Oracle white paper](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/bi-datawarehousing/twp-optimizer-with-oracledb-12c-1963236.pdf).  It means that the optimizer can change it query execution plan while it is running.  But if you don't index columns that could benefit from them, the optimizer will not be able to (adaptively or otherwise) choose a plan that would benefit from those indexes!